# Test reading from a file using GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest

I am trying to test a document reader using Google Test. 
My code is organized as follow: there is a `Document` class which opens the file. A document contains one or more `Element`, which is a `struct` with a pointer (`field`) to a wstring and `value`.
Obviously I would like to open the file just once and then cycle though the various `Elements`.

```
class DocumentTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
  virtual void SetUp() {
  string path = "path/to/file";
  Document doc;
  doc.Open(path);      
}

  Element* el;
  el = doc.Read();
};

TEST_F(DocumentTest, ReadTest) {
    while (file has still elements) {
      wchar_t* expectedField = L"expectingThis";
      wchar_t* readString = el->field;
      EXPECT_EQ(expectedField,readString);
    }
```

but this is clearly not working. Where should I declare my init code?

Comment: Is the duplicated `el = doc.Read()` a copy/paste error? Also, it should be `TEST_F(DocumentTest, ...)`, if that's your test class name. Use [this example](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample3_unittest.cc) as a template, that's the easiest way. Also, check [other samples](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Samples).

Comment: yes, thanks for spotting it. I have tried to mimic that example, and this was my result

Comment: You cannot have code outside of a function in C (or C++), examine the example more thoroughly. Those two `Element* el` lines belong inside the `TEST_F` macro. I also presume `doc.Read()` will return `null` once you reach EOF, but it's impossible to know that without knowing how that function is written.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md

In general googletest allows three different modes of resource management:

- `SetUp` and `TearDown()` (run before and after each test function)
- `SetUpTestCase()` and `TearDownTestCase()` (run before and after each class, or "Case")
- The `Environment` class which is run before/after the first and last test, respectively.